# Will Changing Country Change Language

Tags: internationalization, language

So I am a switching to the Mac guy and I have a query.
Once I get my new Mac it seems I am asked to setup my country.

**Say if I set the country to be Germany will it change the interface language to be German as well or will it still be English?**

Thanks.
P.S. : If I purchase the Mac from Germany and set it to my original home country will it create a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select German as installation language your OS X installation and UI will be in German. You can always your change your system (UI) and input language or use multiple languages at the same time.

It doesn't matter where you buy your Mac. However please note, a German MacBook will include a German keyboard. Some local stores also sell english keyboards as well..

Comment: Thanks. So setting the country doesn't change the language? I am getting an English keyboard online :)

Comment: It doesn't unless you change it.